# Can not read data using NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsthread, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am trying to read an array from Core Data. My code is as follows

```
-(NSArray *)getAges
{
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil; 
    context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    @try {
         NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *tempCordinator = (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] persistentStoreCoordinator];
            [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:tempCordinator];

        NSError *error;
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Age" 
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"core data exception occured.");
        fetchedObjects = nil;
    }
    [fetchRequest release];
    [context release];

    return fetchedObjects;
}
```

Now in main thread, in an IBAction method, I write following line.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadAgesMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Problem is that this method returns me an array of 20 elements. I can see the array count 20 but in debugger, against every element of array, i see 'out of scope' and 'summary unavailable'. And when I try to fetch any object from this array, i get nothing. One thing is to mention is that I am calling this method getAges in loadAgesMethod from a secondary thread as I mentioned above. This is my requirement. Also when I try to retrieve this array from main thread, i get all data perfectly ok.

Can anyone please give me a hint, where I am wrong?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Every NSManagedObject has a NSManagedObjectContext property.  This is used to lazily fetch properties of the object when required in the future.  At the end of this method you call [context release] hence the NSManagedObjectContext will be deallocated and all your NSManagedObject context properties will be nil for your Age objects.

You could call [context autorelease] on the context so that it persists for some time after the method and allows you to fetch properties on the objects at a later stage.  Note this will only persist until the autorelease pool drains at the end of the run loop.  I am still trying myself to come up with a better solution to multithreaded fetching.